# JTable change color for entire column when values changed - Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I tried to find here for a long time answer for my question but without the exact result i expected.

I have JTable which every time i am changing values in entire column (only in one column every time).
I want to listen to a table changes and when data changes in the column, the color in the column will be changed too and all other columns will be in the default color.

This is the code for the table listener:

```
Class CustomCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component rendererComp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                if(***here i want to know which column changed or something like that***){
                    rendererComp.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                }

            }
        });

        return rendererComp ;
    }

}
```

and this is the code for the table creation:

```
private void createTable() {

        tablePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }
        };
        contentTable = new JTable(tableModel);

        contentTable.setGridColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        for(int i=0; i<columnSize; i++) {
            tableModel.addColumn("0");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<rawSize; i++) {
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[] { "" });
        }

        for(int i=0; i<rawSize; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<tableModel.getRowCount(); j++) {
                tableModel.setValueAt("0", j, i);
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<ramSize; i++) {
            contentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(new CustomCellRenderer());
        }

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(contentTable);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));

        tablePanel.add(scrollPane);
}
```

Comment: *"This is the code for the table listener:"* Given it would not compile as shown, I doubt that. 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Sorry for that, i did not know the code should compile. it will not compile because i do not really know what to write in the if section i asked here and this is why i wrote if(***here i want to know which column changed or something like that***).

Comment: `I want to listen to a table changes and when data changes in the column, the color in the column will be changed too and all other columns will be in the default color.` == `prepareRenderer`, just, only, nothing to do with TableModelListener (something will/can be fired outside from JTable/Model to the rest of GUI or variables), possible with  getTableCellRenderer too, don't forget to override `getColumnClass` too

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will search about prepareRendere and getColumnClass. Actually I am new in the swing business so I would love if there was a short example, even general one.

Comment: Do you want the entire column colored 1) after you have edited a single cell or 2) after you have edited all cells in the column?

Comment: i am editing the entire column in one loop like this one,
contentTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnNotInUse).setHeaderValue(pageId);

   for(int i=0; i<PageNumbers.length; i++) {
    contentTable.setValueAt(PageNumbers[i], i, columnNotInUse);
   }

   contentTable.repaint();
and now i want after editing the entire column to change the entire column color

Comment: even after every cell change it will be ok in same loop. i have a play button that if someone click it the column changes entirely and the user seeing it immediately and not one by one.

Comment: @mKorbel is correct; manage state in the `TableModel`, where you can fire the appropriate event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the desired state in the `TableModel`; let the `TableCellRenderer` use the state to condition the view accordingly. In the example below, as soon as `setValueAt()` updates any cell, `edited` is marked `true`. The render, which is applied to column zero, changes the display accordingly. Note how `clearEdited()` invokes `fireTableDataChanged()` to force the table to render all cells when called in the <kbd>Clear</kbd> handler.

Addendum: The update below shows one approach to handling multiple columns independently. The `CustomModel` now contains a `Map<Integer, Boolean>` to store the edited state for each column to which the `CustomRenderer` is applied. As an aside, the `CustomRenderer` now invokes `convertColumnIndexToModel()` and sets the selection color correctly.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37439731/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        CustomModel model = new CustomModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"A", "B"});
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            model.addRow(new String[]{"A:" + i, "B:" + i});
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(100, getRowHeight() * getRowCount() / 2);
            }
        };
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer(model));
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer(model));
        f.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JButton(new UpdateAction("Update A", model, 0)));
        p.add(new JButton(new UpdateAction("Update B", model, 1)));
        p.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Clear") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.clearEdited(0);
                model.clearEdited(1);
            }
        }));
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class CustomModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private final Map<Integer, Boolean> edited = new HashMap<>();

        public boolean isEdited(int column) {
            return edited.get(column) != null && edited.get(column);
        }

        public void clearEdited(int column) {
            edited.put(column, false);
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
            edited.put(column, true);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private final CustomModel model;

        public CustomRenderer(CustomModel model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            if (model.isEdited(table.convertColumnIndexToModel(col))) {
                c.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            } else if (isSelected) {
                c.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return c;
        }
    }

    private static class UpdateAction extends AbstractAction {

        private final CustomModel model;
        private final int column;

        public UpdateAction(String name, CustomModel model, int column) {
            super(name);
            this.model = model;
            this.column = column;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                model.setValueAt(model.getValueAt(i, column), i, column);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, first of all it is a major progress for me, i really appreciate your answer and your help.
i am just trying one last thing that i could not figure out. when i am changing values in a column the color changes to CYAN but when i change the values in other column the color changes also but the other column still in CYAN which i want it to be back in white like the original color and just the new column to be in CYAN, can i do something like that? in you example lets say if you will click one more time on update the first column will be default color again and the second will be in CYAN.

Comment: In the model, use a `List<Boolean>` to store the state for each column to which you apply the renderer; pass the column index to `isEdited()`.

Comment: i am really sorry for saying that but i am really an ignorant in this field.
i am trying to add the List and totally messing it up.

Comment: made it! i just added a loop for all column setCellRenderer to be null and then initialised only the one i want to colorise. thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @Danny: Instead of `List<Boolean>`, `Map<Integer, Boolean>` turned out to be easier; also note a few corrections to the renderer.